# Scale distance between meshes

Tags: transforms

I know I can scale the distance between objects with the option below

[image: Distance between objects]

Does it exist something similar for meshes into the same object (edit mode)?

Thanks

Comment: Break them up into separate objects, use the mentioned option then join them back into one object

Comment: There are hundred of meshes (cubes) not so easy

Comment: If not possible in Edit mode (let's see if anybody has a solution), It could be separated by Loose parts ("P" key) and do what Duarte said... not so easy but a bit easy